# Mapping Pivot table to original table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with more than 20000 rows and created a PIVOT table based on these rows. One of the columns in the table is the row number. Based on some criteria, I need to identify some faulty rows in my original table.

Each row in the original table corresponds to one unique cell in the pivot table.
I could highlight the corresponding cell in the pivot table by changing the color to yellow but how do I map this back to my original table. I am thinking of writing some logic to loop through the pivot table, identify the cells with color yellow and get the details of the cells in the original table.

Can someone help me get the color of the cell of the pivot table and mark the corresponding row in the original table ?

Comment: you can double click on the cell in the pivot table that is wrong, and get to see the data that is producing the error. You should then be able to refer to the original data to see which record(s) correspond to the ones excel puts on the new sheet

Comment: The problem is I have atleast around 500 cells which I need. Is there a way to get the row number in vba ?